# Cannot use conda-forge to install psycopg2 library

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, conda, psycopg2, conda-forge

Up until last week, I was running a powershell script to install python libraries on a server. I first install `miniconda` and then use `conda` to install my libraries like this:

```
Start-Process "$condaInstaller" -argumentlist "/InstallationType=AllUsers /RegisterPython=0 /S /D=d:\miniconda3" -wait
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
log ("$(Get-Date) --- installing conda packages")

invoke-expression 'd:\miniconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1'

conda activate base
conda install -y -c conda-forge GDAL=3.6.4
conda install -y -c conda-forge geopandas=0.12.2
conda install -y -c conda-forge boto3
conda install -y -c conda-forge psycopg2
conda install -y -c conda-forge pytest
conda install -y -c conda-forge requests

Set-Location d:\my-repo
python -m pip install .
conda deactivate
```

After the script runs, all the libraries are installed in the newly created `base` environment, except psycopg2. When I try to run `conda install -y -c conda-forge psycopg2` from my terminal, it returns this:

```
(base) D:\my-repo>conda install -y -c conda-forge psycopg2
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - conda==23.3.1
```

Whats going on here? This was working fine up until last week and now it won't install. I don't see any deprecation messages in the `psycopg2` or `conda-forge` reference pages. Could there be some firewall rule or security patch that might be causing this? Any clue how to resolve this?

Comment: Not answering the problem directly, but Micromamba + YAML would be more state-of-the-art. Indirectly, `micromamba` is a static build, so it does not care about any such `conda` package in a **base** environment. (Otherwise, one shouldn't be using **base** environment for "work".)